# Apache Hive configuration in GCP - clueless?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, g-suite

I have tried to configure an Apache Hive Cluster in GCP using the following link on the Google Cloud Platform.

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-apache-hive-on-cloud-dataproc

I have set up a project and have a whole years worth of credits available. The script mentioned in this page uses the Google Shell to confugure the cluster instead of using the GCP UI.

Herein lies the problem, I carry out all the steps above and just as I am about to create the cluster using the following command - "It fails" !!

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create hive-cluster. \
    --scopes sql-admin \
    --image-version 1.3 \
    --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/cloud-sql-proxy/cloud-sql-proxy.sh \
    --properties hive:hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=gs://$PROJECT-warehouse/datasets \
    --metadata "hive-metastore-instance=$PROJECT:$REGION:hive-metastore"
```

The error I get is ***"Insufficient 'CPUS' quota. Requested 12.0, available 8.0."***

Now here is the problem. If I had used the GCP UI - dataproc to create the cluster, I could have been able to configured the CPU's. But that option has its own limitations with respect to Hive.

So I had to launch the cluster pro grammatically via the shell. Now I don;t know how to fix this, unless I physically open every shell script available on the google bucket and find where these values have been set.

Any help anyone? Maybe I should be looking at this differently...

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is only related with a quota issue it has an easy solution, just request an increase of CPU quota.

1. Go to your [Quotas page](https://cloud.console.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) in the Google Cloud Console.
2. In the Quotas page, select the quotas you want to change.
3. Click the Edit Quotas button on the top of the page.
4. Check the box of the service you want to edit, in this case **"Compute Engine API"** and the metric **"CPU"**.
5. Fill out your name, email, and phone number and click Next.
6. Enter your request to increase your quota and click Next.
7. Submit your request.
8. You will receive a response from the Compute Engine team within 24 to 48 hours of your request.